# Cant Change Encryption Options in Gnome-Disks

Tags: gnome, mount, encryption, automount

When I try to change encryption options to automatically unencrypt a partition by going through the GUI entering the partition passphrase and the root password I get this error:

Failed to open file /etc/crypttab: No such file or directory (g-file-error-quark, 4)

How can I solve this? Before I reinstalled ubuntu, I was able to do this, although I remember getting this exact same error before, but I'm not sure what solved it. It might have been creating a crypttab file by 'touch /etc/crypttab' that solved the problem before. But it doesn't work now.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107810/why-my-encrypted-lvm-volume-luks-device-wont-mount-at-boot-time

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, just touch the file with this command

```
    sudo touch /etc/crypttab
```

Then I tried again and it worked.